# Return value false to stop ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var filterval = filterlist();
if (filterval) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "filt.php",
        data: main_string, 
        cache: false,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {}
    });
}

filterlist() {
    var fprice = $('input[name="fprice"]').val();
    var lprice = $('input[name="lprice"]').val();
    if (fprice >= lprice) {
        alert("Value Wrong");
        return false;
    }
    else if (fprice == "" || lprice == "") {
        alert("price empty");
        return false;
    }
    return fprice + " " + lprice;
}
```

I expectation is

1. `Filterlist()` function value false to AJAX process stop.
2. Value not false to work on ajax process .

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: `parseInt` or `parseFloat` the input value and then compare...

Comment: You cannot stop an AJAX request. All you can do is `abort()` it, but this just means that the client doesn't care about the result anymore, the server will still receive and process the request. It's like trying to stop a bullet after it's been fired. Also note that the syntax of your `filterlist()` function declaration is incorrect.

Comment: see `filterval` if it has any truthy value only in that case it would run otherwise it not.

Comment: As rory mentioned `function filterlist() {` function keyword is missing.

Comment: i have use parseInt its working.Thank you  @RayonDabre

Answer (score 0):

```
 var fprice = parseInt($('input[name="fprice"]').val());
 var lprice = parseInt($('input[name="lprice"]').val());
```

Use parseInt to convert fprice and price into numbers(from strings) and then compairing is possible :)